# Magento 2 block controller action not calling second time

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

I have a block in my module and when the block is loaded first time it will calling the controller and I am getting the url parameters,but when the block open with same url parameters then the controller is not calling.

```
http://127.0.0.1/magentotest/myintegration/mymodule/link/code/12345/ClickId/1200
```

this link will open a block and the controller is calling so that I am getting the url parameters,like **code** and **clickId**

but next time when I hit the same url with same parameters then the controller is not calling and I am not getting the url parameters.

After clear the magento cache then it will calling.So what is the reason for not calling the controller second time with same parameter values?

Comment: did you use varnish cache?

Comment: @BilalUsean I am a beginner,I don't know about varnish cache,so how to use it?is it solve my issue?

Answer (score 0):

This is a cache issue in localhost.

Kidly, disable **Blocks HTML outputs** cache

[image]

You can also disable this cache using CLI using following command

```
php bin/magento cache:disable block_html
```

If this helps then hit like and share.

Thank you,
Hiren Patel

Comment: not working,same issue